# Selenium Test (junit ) get stuck once the test spawns new window

Tags: selenium, automation, automated-tests, integration-testing, junit4

Issue is once the new window is spawn test hangs after the line waitForPageToLoad(3000) and finally times out. Once the test hangs if i manually fire some event in parent window test starts executing normally. So as a solution I tried adding code that selects parent window and fire some event. But this code doesn't work at all. If any one could point out where am I missing something or point out my wrong approach.

**Steps I followed :**

1. Click the link that opens new window.(***here link=3018***)
2. Once the new **window2** opens no further action is automated and test just hangs until timeout interval after which it just throws timeout exception.
3. Manually fire event(**click link=outbox**) on parent **window1** before timeout interval.
4. Test start executing normaly and finish successfully.

**Code snippet (that works fine once manually firing evnt in parent window) :**

```
            selenium.click("link=Last");
            selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
            selenium.click("link=3018");
            selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");              
            selenium.selectWindow("window2");
            selenium.selectFrame("relative=up");
            selenium.click("687c55");
            selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
            assertEquals("window2", selenium.getTitle());
            selenium.close();
```

**Code snippet (that fails evn after adding code to select window and firing evnt in parent window) :**

```
            selenium.click("link=Last");
            selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
            selenium.click("link=3018");
            selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
            selenium.selectWindow("window1");              
            selenium.click("link=Outbox");
            selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
            selenium.selectWindow("window2");
            selenium.selectFrame("relative=up");
            selenium.click("687c55");
            selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
            assertEquals("window2", selenium.getTitle());
            selenium.close();
```

I cannot find any reason why my code still fails after adding code to select parent window and to fire click event. It still just hangs and throws exception after time out. :(

Is there any bug with selenium handling popup windows ?
Would like to have any suggestion regarding modification in my approach for handling pop up windows in selenium

Answer (score 0):

Selenium RC handles pop-up windows just fine.  Lots of our tests use them.  You don't make it clear what command is timing out, but I'll guess it's either the `selectWindow("window2")` or the `selectFrame("relative=up")`.

If the former, you've probably got the wrong window name - you should be using the same value as used in `window.open(url, name, ...)`.

If the latter, well, does the pop-up window have multiple frames in it?  In fact, now that I think about it, this is probably the failing command, as even in a multi-frame window, Selenium starts out focused on the topmost frame, so `"relative=up"` wouldn't work.

Comment: well as i wrote (step 1 and step 2) the script hangs just after executing the  selenium.click("link=3018") and **selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000")**

As a result of which new window is opened successfully but no further automation turns out due to hang up.
Once I will fire some event in the window1 after the hang up, everything is automated again. Thanks

Comment: Well, then, that's your problem.  If the click() is what opens the window, Selenium isn't ever going to see the original window load a page - that's happening in the OTHER window.  Your selectWindow() needs to be between the click() and the waitForPageToLoad().  You may need to wait for it to be present, but that's another topic.